# Php Foreach if ... Zend framework ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, zend-framework

I'm new to php and mysql and i'm working on a Zend Projet.
I have to display shops with ajax request onthe town. 
Ajax Part seems to be ok, but i have trouble with the php part :

```
var_dump($this->Boutiques_Details); 

array (size=565)
  0 => 
    array (size=5)
      'ville' => string 'Fès' (length=4)
      'adresse' => string 'Av Slaoui Resid Des Palmiers Vn Fes' (length=35)
      'quartier' => string 'Ville Nouvelle' (length=14)
      'id' => string '1' (length=1)
      'num_contact_1' => string '212534017800' (length=12)
  1 => 
    array (size=5)
      'ville' => string 'Casablanca' (length=10)
      'adresse' => string 'Angle bd Bir Anzarane et Caid Al Achtar' (length=39)
      'quartier' => string 'Maârif' (length=7)
      'id' => string '2' (length=1)
      'num_contact_1' => string '212529004563' (length=12)
  2 => 
    array (size=5)
      'ville' => string 'Marrakech' (length=9)
      'adresse' => string '2 Angle Bd Zerktouni et Rue Liban' (length=33)
      'quartier' => string 'Gueliz' (length=6)
      'id' => string '3' (length=1)
      'num_contact_1' => string '212529800027' (length=12)
  3 => 
    array (size=5)
      'ville' => string 'Rabat' (length=5)
      'adresse' => string 'N° 1  Angle avenue des nations unies & Av Omar Ibn khattab Agdal' (length=65)
      'quartier' => string 'Agdal' (length=5)
      'id' => string '4' (length=1)
      'num_contact_1' => string '212699529702' (length=12)
  4 => 
    array (size=5)
      'ville' => string 'Casablanca' (length=10)
      'adresse' => string 'Angle Bd hassan II & Bd de Paris ' (length=33)
      'quartier' => string 'Centre ville' (length=12)
      'id' => string '5' (length=1)
      'num_contact_1' => string '212529008573' (length=12)
  5 => 
    array (size=5)
      'ville' => string 'Tanger' (length=6)
      'adresse' => string 'bd pasteur sour meaagazine' (length=26)
      'quartier' => string 'sour meaagazin' (length=14)
      'id' => string '6' (length=1)
      'num_contact_1' => string '212538800322' (length=12)
  6 => 
    array (size=5)
      'ville' => string 'Meknès' (length=7)
      'adresse' => string '6 Av Hassan II - ville nouvelle' (length=31)
      'quartier' => string 'Hemria' (length=6)
      'id' => string '7' (length=1)
      'num_contact_1' => string '212533548651' (length=12)
  7 => 
    array (size=5)
      'ville' => string 'Oujda' (length=5)
      'adresse' => string 'Angle Bd Mohamed V et Bd ahfir, N°1' (length=36)
      'quartier' => string 'Centre Ville' (length=12)
      'id' => string '8' (length=1)
      'num_contact_1' => string '212600001005 ' (length=14)
```

As you can see it's an array of array.

```
var_dump($this->ville);
```

return : string 'Agadir' (length=6)

So i have to do a foreach with a if setting but I *** dont know how to do that... Please Help meeee

EDIT : 
The loop :

```
foreach( $this->Boutiques_Details as $arr ){
    foreach( $arr as $key => $value ){
        if ($key['ville'] == $this->ville)
        {        
        echo $key . " " . $value;
        }
    }
}
```

I have no error but the if condition return nothing

Comment: You already have the answer. Use loops. Try by yourself and then put what you attempt to  do.

Comment: I already try like 1000times :D I'm trying a 1001 and i edit my post

Comment: If you just take a look at my answer you already have it ;)

Comment: Thanks men. I just try but always the same invalid argument, is $this->Boutiques_Details correct for a loop ?

Comment: What are you exactly doing?

Comment: If you copy/past his code it's should work. Last point, he missed to check for the city (if the `$this->ville` match the `$key['ville']`). `foreach( $this->Boutiques_Details as $boutique => $this->ville )` <= you can't do that.

Comment: @Debflav That's why I always use `$key => $value`. So if he would copy my answer it must work.

Comment: @GuyT Fully agree. lovis91 you should learn the foreach loop.

Comment: Yes i'm trying to.. I try to copy paste but always same mistake. Im although try to add the if

Comment: The loop works finaly but the if returns nothing

Comment: And the if work too : if (($this->ville) == ($arr['ville'])  ). A big thanks for you two guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use propertynames in the `foreach`. In PHP the `foreach` syntax is like:

```
foreach( $this->Boutiques_Details as $arr ){
    foreach( $arr as $key => $value ){
        echo $key . " " . $value;
    }
}
```

ps. Do not swear. You doesn't look smarter if you do that(a bit immature instead).

Answer (score 1):

You can use only one foreach like this:

```
foreach( $this->Boutiques_Details as $key => $value){
     if ($value['ville'] == $this->ville) {        
         echo $key . " " . $value;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks it work too. But i have an other problem : my results are in <div> and even the divs with nothing in it are created..

Comment: you need check the content before echo the results.